# dynamically adding unlimited fields to wordpress custom post

Tags: wordpress

does anybody know a plugin for wordpress custom fields that will allow me dynamically  add unlimited number of custom field for post in post adding/editing page. for example "Key Features field/child post" of some product which is post itself and must be added dynamically and unlimited while adding parent post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gravity Forms and the Gravity Forms and the Gravity Forms Custom Post Type Plugin. Most form controls allow "if..then" logic to be applied. Advanced Custom Fields may also be an option. However, either way you will have to add a custom post type. If you edit post.php then you will lose your changes the next time WP updates.

Start by creating a custom post type with http://generatewp.com/post-type/. I know its not a plug in like you asked for but You might find a way to accomplish the functionality.

Comment: i used plugin called Types and configured relationship. but thnx anyways